# XSLT Values By Number

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am trying to extract the values for the duration timecode in order by segment number.

Here is an example of my input xml:

```
<Container>
    <Properties outputFileSegment-1-durationTimeCode="00:00:59;28" outputFileSegment-1-durationTotalFrames="1798" outputFileSegment-1-endTimeCode="00:59:39;29" outputFileSegment-1-endTimeCodeMediaflex="00:59:40;00" outputFileSegment-1-endTotalFrames="107291" outputFileSegment-1-endTotalFramesMediaflex="107292" outputFileSegment-1-segmentType="12" outputFileSegment-1-startTimeCode="00:58:40;00" outputFileSegment-1-startTotalFrames="105494" outputFileSegment-2-durationTimeCode="00:00:17;28" outputFileSegment-2-durationTotalFrames="540" outputFileSegment-2-endTimeCode="00:59:57;29" outputFileSegment-2-endTimeCodeMediaflex="00:59:58;00" outputFileSegment-2-endTotalFrames="107831" outputFileSegment-2-endTotalFramesMediaflex="107832" outputFileSegment-2-segmentType="8" outputFileSegment-2-startTimeCode="00:59:40;00" outputFileSegment-2-startTotalFrames="107292" outputFileSegment-3-durationTimeCode="00:09:06;17" outputFileSegment-3-durationTotalFrames="16379" outputFileSegment-3-endTimeCode="01:09:06;06" outputFileSegment-3-endTimeCodeMediaflex="01:09:06;20" outputFileSegment-3-endTotalFrames="124260" outputFileSegment-3-endTotalFramesMediaflex="124261" outputFileSegment-3-segmentType="63" outputFileSegment-3-startTimeCode="00:59:59;20" outputFileSegment-3-startTotalFrames="107882" />
</Container>
```

What I trying to accomplish is a final format similar to this output:

```
<segment>
    <segment_sequence_number>1</segment_sequence_number>
    <segment_length>00:00:59;28</segment_length>
</segment>
<segment>
    <segment_sequence_number>2</segment_sequence_number>
    <segment_length>00:00:17;28</segment_length>
</segment>
<segment>
    <segment_sequence_number>3</segment_sequence_number>
    <segment_length>00:09:06;17</segment_length>
</segment>
```

I am stuck at this point because I do not know how to write in xslt 1.0 to extract the values for each duration in order until the last segment. Could someone please help me get on the right track?

Comment: Please explain the logic required for the transformation. Is there a fixed number of segments? Or at least a maximum number of segments? Why does your output contain only the first two segments, but not the third? And how should you calculate the length of a segment (there is no frame rate in your input)?

Comment: There is not a fixed number of segments, I need to find a transform that will output the duration until the last segment (whether it is 4 segments or 25). The output is an example of what I need to create, it is not the exact output for this specific input. We do not need to calculate using frame rate. That has been done for me already. I simply need to use the durationTimeCode value to fill segment_length.

Comment: I don't see that every segment *has* a `durationTimeCode`. And the one that has, has a different value than the one in your output. Your question is difficult enough already, please make it easier for us to understand it. -- Also please state if you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I have updated the question above. I have to use XSLT 1.0 for this transform.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit  because it made no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Container">
    <segments>
        <xsl:for-each select="Properties/@*[substring-after(substring-after(name(), '-'), '-')='durationTimeCode']">
            <segment>
                <segment_sequence_number>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(name(), '-'), '-')" />
                </segment_sequence_number>
                <segment_length>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </segment_length>
            </segment>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </segments>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am very new to XSLT. Will I then need to apply this template at another point in my XSLT? I have used your information but still come up with no values unformatunaly

Comment: @user6391187 This is a complete XSLT stylesheet. It assumes your input XML structure is exactly what you posted above - and nothing else. If you have other nodes to handle, then you will need to adapt this into your stylesheet - and I cannot help you with that without seeing the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

It's an obscene way of using XML to have structured attributes like this, and generally when you see such badly designed XML, the best thing to do is to start by transforming it to good XML, and then work with the good XML for your real logic. For this input I would start by transforming it to something like this:

```
<Container>
    <Properties>
      <segment nr="1">
          <durationTimeCode>00:00:59;28</durationTimeCode>
          <durationTotalFrames>1798</durationTotalFrames>
          <endTimeCode>00:59:39;29</endTimeCode>
          ...
      </segment>
      <segment nr="2">
          ...
      </segment>
   </Properties>
</Container>
```

This clean up can be achieved using the following template rules. I've used XSLT 2.0 because it involves grouping and string matching and I really can't stomach tackling that in 1.0, if you really need that I'll leave you to do the Muenchian legwork yourself.

```
<xsl:template match="Properties">
  <Properties>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="@*" group-by="replace(name(), '[-A-Za-z]', '')">
      <segment nr="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <xsl:element name="replace(name(), '^[A-Za-z]-[0-9]-', '')">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </segment>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </Properties>
</xsl:template>
```

I think this is the first time in my life I have ever done grouping on the attributes of an element; that's a measure of just how weird this XML input is.